# Assign Function to Dynamically Loaded Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a WYSIWYG editor plugin for jQuery called wysibb

I'm attempting to do this:

```
$("#editor").wysibb();
```

But I am loading pages via jQuery load and when I do this, the .wysibb(); does not assign to the dynamically loaded content. I have to refresh the page for it to be loaded.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You have to call `$("#editor").wysibb()` every time you load a new page. So in the callback of load you have to call `$("#editor").wysibb()`

Comment: Thank you very much @ThomasDevries